# Infowindow on a Image Map (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infowindow, imagemap

I want to display a infowindow on image map when I click on the link .

here is my code :

```
<img src="[http://www.isdntek.com/tagbot/misc/bambi.jpg][1]" width="400" border="0" usemap="#imap_51" >
<map id="imap_51" name="imap_51" >
<area shape="rect" coords="27,47,135,135"  title="info1" href="">
<area shape="rect" coords="188,26,296,114"  title="info2" href="">
<area shape="rect" coords="116,140,224,228"  title="inf33" href="">
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show info window (assuming you mean alert) like this (without jQuery):

```js
function showInfo(target) {
    // target is the clicked area element
    alert(target.title);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.isdntek.com/tagbot/misc/bambi.jpg" width="400" usemap="#imap_51" />
<map id="imap_51" name="imap_51" >
    <area shape="rect" coords="27,47,135,135"  title="info1" onclick="return showInfo(this);" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="188,26,296,114"  title="info2" onclick="return showInfo(this);" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="116,140,224,228"  title="inf33" onclick="return showInfo(this);" />
</map>
```

and using jquery:

```js
$(function() {
    // Get all area elements and assing click handler
    $("area").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Show alert
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.isdntek.com/tagbot/misc/bambi.jpg" width="400" usemap="#imap_51" />
<map id="imap_51" name="imap_51" >
    <area shape="rect" coords="27,47,135,135"  title="info1" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="188,26,296,114"  title="info2" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="116,140,224,228"  title="inf33" />
</map>
```